# how to change value from text file to number

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I get variable from text file but I want to change format from text to number its is possible?

```
var fs = require('fs');

try {  
    var mobileNumber = fs.readFileSync('text.txt', 'utf8');
    var amount = fs.readFileSync('text2.txt', 'utf8');

    const payload = generate(mobileNumber, { amount })
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information here. What exactly is the value you want to convert?

Comment: i want to convert text file value to number value

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
var amount = Number(fs.readFileSync('text2.txt', 'utf8'));
```